# Consolidating input elements containing lamba expressions in ASP.NET MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC view that contains a lot of similar code and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to consolidate it.  Here is a sample for Question1, and I want to produce the same for 18 questions.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1Type)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1Type)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1Type)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1Required)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question1Required)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1Required)
</div>
```

Is there a way to iterate through a loop for all the questions or some other mechanism in MVC to consolidate this code for 18 questions?

Comment: PartialView-s is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work:

```
@{
  var properties = new List<Func<Model, object>> 
                   { 
                       model => model.Question1, 
                       model => model.Question1Type, 
                       model => model.Question1Required
                   };
 }
 @foreach( property in properties ) {
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(property )
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(property )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(property )
     </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this article. It explain how to bind a view from a list.
With just some adjustment on your ViewModel it can be useful also for you, I believe.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx